# US travel visa after an overstay

Tags: visas, usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, overstaying

I overstayed my 90-day visa by roughly 23 days in September 2013. I desperately want to return to the US for a week. Am I eligible to enter us again, as it has been 3 years? Does my ban come into effect when I left or does it start when I try to re-enter? If I am allowed to re-enter, would I just apply via ESTA.

Answer (score 11):

When you say you overstayed "my 90 day visa", do you by any chance mean that you were admitted for 90 days **without having a visa**, under the Visa Waiver Program?

If so, having overstayed once makes you **forever ineligible** to use the VWP again, pursuant to [8 U.S.C. 1187](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1187)(a)(7).

You can apply for a B-1/B-2 visa for your trip, but during the application you will have to disclose that you have a previous overstay (otherwise it's visa fraud which *will* earn you a ban), so you'd better have a good and convincing story ready about why you overstayed and how they can be sure you won't do so again.

---

If you entered **on an actual visa** before overstaying, then it doesn't look like a 23-day overstay will make you inadmissible, so in principle you can just apply for an ESTA in that case.

Be sure to answer "yes" to the *"Have you ever stayed in the United States longer than the admission period granted to you by the U.S. government?"* question on the ESTA form -- lying there will get you in considerably hotter water than the overstay itself will. It wouldn't surprise me if the ESTA is rejected on this ground (though I cannot find any source that outright says it must), so apply sufficiently long time in advance that you have time to apply for a visa if that happens.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I overstayed purely for the reason I loved the place. My esta was refused so I will have to try the B-2 now I have a family now so hopefully at interview they will see ive every intention of returning home

Comment: @Dw464 try to prepare and bring bring all the proof of your intent to return you can think of to the interview to  maximise your chances - employment contracts, rent/mortgage contracts, etc.etc.

Comment: And unfortunately "I loved the place" is not exactly an explanation that suggests you're likely to abide by the visa rules in the future...

Comment: @Dw464 "I overstayed purely for the reason I loved the place" Surely you must have realised it would come to this? Or did you think the US wasn't "that strict" regarding overstays?